# @Jacksonized deserialization doesn't work with mixins - "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"

Tags: java, csv, jackson, lombok

I'm trying to deserialize an array of `MyObject` (which uses the builder pattern via Lombok with `@Jacksonized`) from a csv String containing a non-standard representation of a map as one of the columns.

MyObject:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "strField",
        "mapField",
})
@Getter
@Jacksonized
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class MyObject {

    private final String strField;

    @Builder.Default
    private final Map<String, Float> mapField = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Example csv with non-standard `mapField` representation:

```
strField,mapField
abc,"key1=2.0;key2=3.0"
```

I'm using a mixin to try to achieve this without rewriting the entire object:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
            "strField",
            "mapField",
})
public abstract class MyObjectDeserializerMixin {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = StringToMapDeserializer.class)
    private Map<String, Float> mapField;
}
```

..which, as you can see above, points to a custom deserializer:

```
public class StringToMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Float>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Float> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String csvFormattedMap = jsonParser.getText().trim();

        return Arrays.stream(csvFormattedMap.split(";"))
                .map(keyValue -> keyValue.split("="))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyValue -> keyValue[0], keyValue -> Float.parseFloat(keyValue[1])));
    }
}
```

And, to wrap it all up, I'm configuring and using my `CsvMapper` like so:

```
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    csvMapper.addMixIn(MyObject.class, MyObjectDeserializerMixin.class);

    CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper
            .schemaFor(MyObject.class)
            .withHeader();

    ObjectReader csvReader = csvMapper.readerFor(MyObject.class).with(csvSchema);
    List<MyObject> myObjects = csvReader.<MyObject>readValues(theCsvString).readAll();
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one
> Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from String value ('key1=2.0;key2=3.0')  at [Source:
> (StringReader); line: 2, column: 53] (through reference chain:
> myPackage.MyObject$MyObjectBuilder["mapField"])

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1432)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1062)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromString(ValueInstantiator.java:258)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:357)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeSetAndReturn(MethodProperty.java:158)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:269)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:193)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1261)
...
```

The stack trace appears to be trying to use a `BuilderBasedDeserializer` which tries to use a `MapDeserializer.java` for the map so it doesn't appear to be aware of my custom deserializer.  I've used a very similar workflow with a custom **serializer** to write the same csv, so I'm confused as to why this doesn't work.  What is the next step to troubleshooting this?

Comment: Does it work when you add the mixin to `MyObjectBuilder.class` instead of `MyObject.class`?

Comment: @JanRieke using `csvMapper.addMixIn(MyObject.MyObjectBuilder.class, MyObjectDeserializerMixin.class);` did not work, no.

Comment: Strange. I just c&p'ed your example to my IDE and it works when I add the mixin to the builder. Is there something you omitted in your exemplary code here?
Using Lombok 1.18.20 and Jackson 2.12.2.

Comment: I did try to sanitize it a bit - there are more fields in `MyObject`, for instance, and the names are different.. Let me try to reduce my code to this isolated example..  Also the versions I'm using of jackson and lombok are jackson 2.10.3 and lombok 1.18.16

Comment: As the solution works for me, I added an answer. Let's continue the discussion there to get it working for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a builder to deserialize, Jackson only considers the annotations on the builder class, not those on the actual class to deserialize. Lombok's `@Jacksonized` helps you by automatically copying all relevant annotations to the builder class and its setter methods.

However, Lombok can only do that with annotations statically present on the class. Any dynamic annotation coming from a mixin cannot be copied, because Lombok doesn't know about them.
You could put `@JsonDeserialize` onto the `mapField` of the actual class, so that Lombok is able to copy it to the builder. But that obviously runs contrary to the purpose of mixins.

Luckily, there is a better way. You can also add the mixin to the builder class as follows:

```java
csvMapper.addMixIn(MyObjectBuilder.class, MyObjectDeserializerMixin.class);
```

Strictly speaking, you do not need the mixin on `MyObject` any more. But if you also serialize and there are annotations relevant to serialization in the mixin, you should add the mixin to both.

However, in your case, that's not sufficient, as you are using `@Builder.Default`. With that annotation, Lombok creates a field named `mapField$value` in the builder. Jackson will not match the field `mapField` (and its annotation) from your mixin to that field, as they are named differently.
You can work around that by defining and annotating the setter method in your mixin:

```java
public abstract class MyObjectDeserializerMixin {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StringToMapDeserializer.class)
    public abstract void mapField(Map<String, Float> mapField);
}
```

You can use the actual return type of the builder here, but `void` is also sufficient. As `@JsonDeserialize` is only for deserialization purposes, you can safely remove the `mapField` and its annotation from the mixin class.

*Tested with Lombok 1.18.20 and Jackson 2.12.2.*

Comment: Okay.. I made a mistake when sanitizing my example.  I'll update my question. The key difference is that I'm using `@Builder.Default` on `MyObject`'s `mapField` with `mapField = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: I extended my answer to also work for the `@Builder.Default` case.

Comment: Thank you so much.